# Declaring a template class a metatype in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to allow my own vector library to be a meta-type in QT, through the tutorials they teach me the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(class)`.  However my class is a template.  I have been searching around and found an undocumented macro `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE_TEMPLATE_1ARG()`, however I found one bug report on it, and no feedback on whether it was fixed or not.  I've tried using it and it still doesn't register.  The reason is in my `Shader` class of my game engine, I store uniforms and depending on the uniform, it stores the value as a `QVariant`. That is where I am running into a problem. Does anyone know how to register templates for `QMetatypes`?

Answer (score 2):

Qt uses the macro you mention internally, and there is also a 2-argument version.  `QtCore/qmetatype.h` shows some usage examples.  I'm not sure why it does not work as expected for you, I need to see your code to figure out more.

However, there is a workaround that could be acceptable for you: If you know all the possible template arguments you are going to need, you can explicitly declare each template instantiation to be a metatype. E.g., if your template class is called `Foo<T>`, and you know you are going to use only `Foo<int>` and `Foo<float>`, you can just register those:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo<int>)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo<float>)
```